# Создание новой пустой страницы

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Сейчас мой весь проект состоит из одной только страницы(интернет магазин). Я хотел добавить еще одну пустую страницу, создал path /checkout. Но при в воде localhost:3000/checkout,  страница грузит главную  страницу обратно, а контент из файла Checkout.js  добавляет внизу footer-a. Я хочу просто пустую страницу. В чем мржет быть моя ошибка?

```
function App() {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
dispatch(getCategoriesAsync());
}, []);

return (
 <>
    {/*<TopNavMainScreen />*/}
    <TopHeaderMarket /> //Header component
    <MarketHeader /> // Another header component
    <MarketBody /> // Body
    <MarketFooter /> //Footer component
    {/* <CartComponent /> */}

    //-----------------This is how I tried to create new blank page/path/url
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Switch>
            <Route
                path='/checkout'
                component={lazy(() => import('../src/components/checkout/Checkout'))}
            />
        </Switch>
    </Suspense>
</>
);
}

export default App;
```

вместо lazy  я использовал `<Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>` тоже, результат такой же. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке ниже футера увидите:)

Comment: а где Ваш `<Router>`?)

Comment: эммм, не понял?) @Август

Comment: Вы же используете `react-router-dom`? если да, то для построения роутера нужно  начинать с тега `<Router>` и внутри него создавать роуты

Comment: и у Вас нет `<Route>` для корневой страницы ( для `/`). то есть, Вам нужно иметь два `Route`:  для `/checkout` и для `/`

Comment: понял, дошло, спасибо вам большое @Август